# "NameError: name 'response' is not defined when i try to use the variable in Python3

Tags: python, variables

```
import sys

def func2():
    print("1.Type a number ")
    print("2.Exit the program ")
    response = int(input())

func2()

def func1():
        print('Are you sure ? ') 
        print("Yes or No")
        response = input()
        if response == 'Yes':
            sys.exit()
        elif response == "yes":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            func2()

if response == 1:
    secondresponse = input("Print a number ")
    print ("You typed in "+ secondresponse+ ".")
elif response == 2:
    func1()
```

Why does it give me the error NameError: name 'response' is not defined when I called the variable in the function. Or is that not allowed?

Comment: The variable is only defined inside the scope of the function. If you want to use it outside, you need to `return` it from the function or use `global`

Comment: oh thank you so much, I am still a beginner sorry!

Comment: Happy to help, thank you for including good details in your question

Comment: Names and scopes reading: [9.1,9.2,9.3 in the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects); [4.2 Naming and binding in the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

Answer (score 1):

The variable `response` is only defined in the functions `func1` & `func2`:

Right now you're trying to access the variable before it has been defined, therefore producing a `NameError`. Python doesn't know what `response` is as it's not in the same scope as your functions.

Instead, you should return the response from `func2()` and then check the value of `response`.

```py
def func2():
    print("1.Type a number ")
    print("2.Exit the program ")
    response = int(input())
    return response 

...

if func2() == 1:
  ...
```

I would recommend learning more about [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp)

Answer (score 0):

because response is defined inside the function , use global that will solve it

Comment: Using `global` is a bad idea in 99.9% of all cases where someone suggests it. This is such a case.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that for me, so '''return''' is the best option